# Magento 2 unable to add a New Option (Custom Option section)

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I will try to explain how it happened.
There were 3 options already created for a simple product (Custom Options)

size 1

size 2

size 3

when I removed the `size 1` and saved, all options disappeared... then I tried to created a new one by clicking on Add New Option but the click doesn't work anymore

Anyone can tell me how to fix this error?

```
main.CRITICAL: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/xxx/public_html/xxx/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Option.php on line 320 [] []
```